# Creating new features that leak the target in GradientBoosted classification

Tags: classification

I am engineering new features for a classification task that may be leaking the target variable. Hoping to hear some opinions on whether these features can be used or not.

We are classifying payments made to receivers: they can be CORRECT, UNDERPAYMENTS, or OVERPAYMENTS. One feature is the "Assessors" for each payment who calculating payments to receivers. For each payment, then an Assessor can be attributed to an overpayment/underpayment/correct payment.

The new feature will be calculated based on the assessor's amount of CORRECT claims they have assessed. Hence, it will be calculated using the classes of each payment in the training dataset and then attributed to the claims in the test dataset.

The assumption we are making here is that human error made by the assessors is consistent within the ability of each assessor.

Because this requires the target classes to be calculated, is this leaking of the target?

Answer (score 2):

No - it is not data leakage. The historical record of previous predictions of an Assessor is available at prediction time to make a new prediction. The feature is not leaking current target information.

Here is a related example - If you were trying to predict win, loss, or tie in a sporting event. One feature you could have is the number of previous goals scored by a team. That is important feature but does not leak information about the current game.

Comment: This is only true if  the feature is calculated in a proper way. To stay in the example, you need to ensure that the goals scored are only calculated based on the games played prior to the game for which the feature is calculated. For the second game you need to consider only the goals scored in the first game,  for the third game only the goals of the first two games etc..